# How to have my css navbar be proportional to the page

Tags: javascript, html, css, navbar

My (epic) navbar gets messed up when the window is to small, how can I have it shrink proportionally to the page? I've tried a few things but it just shrinks the text size, but the text still ends up longer than the width of the window, with the title in the top left overlapping onto the text.

Here is the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
</head>

<body>
  <header id="nav-wrapper">
    <nav id="nav">
      <div class="nav left">
        <span class="gradient skew">
          <h1 class="logo un-skew"><a href="#home">RiseUpOnario.ca</a></h1>
        </span>
        <button id="menu" class="btn-nav"><span class="fas fa-bars"></span></button>
      </div>
      <div class="nav right">
        <a href="#home" class="nav-link active"><span class="nav-link-span"><span class="u-nav">Home</span></span></a>
        <a href="#blog" class="nav-link"><span class="nav-link-span"><span class="u-nav">Blog</span></span></a>
        <a href="#join" class="nav-link"><span class="nav-link-span"><span class="u-nav">Join</span></span></a>
        <a href="#donate" class="nav-link"><span class="nav-link-span"><span class="u-nav">Donate</span></span></a>
        <a href="#mppfiner" class="nav-link"><span class="nav-link-span"><span class="u-nav">MPP Finder</span></span></a>
        <a href="#aboutus" class="nav-link"><span class="nav-link-span"><span class="u-nav">About Us</span></span></a>
        <a href="#contact" class="nav-link"><span class="nav-link-span"><span class="u-nav">Contact</span></span></a>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <main>
    <section id="home">
    </section>

    <section id="blog">
    </section>

    <section id="join">
    </section>

    <section id="donate">
    </section>

    <section id="mppfinder">
    </section>

    <section id="aboutus">
    </section>

    <section id="contact">
    </section>
  </main>

</body>

</html>





<style>
/*-------------Reset-------------*/
button {
  background: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

button:focus,
input:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

/*-------------Layout-------------*/
body {
  line-height: 1.5em;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

section {
  height: 100vh;
}

#home {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

#blog {
  background-color: #aaa;
}

#join {
  background-color: #888;
}

#donate {
  background-color: #666;
}

#mppfinder {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

#aboutus {
  background-color: #aaa;
}

#contact {
  background-color: #666;
}

/*-------------Helpers-------------*/
.skew {
  transform: skew(-20deg);
}

.un-skew {
  transform: skew(20deg);
}

/*-------------Nav-------------*/
#nav-wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 100;
}

#nav {
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  font-family: "Saira Semi Condensed", sans-serif;
  height: 4em;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#nav.nav-visible {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

.nav {
  display: flex;
  height: 4em;
  line-height: 4em;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.nav-link,
.logo {
  padding: 0 1em;
}

span.gradient {
  background: #e9b1a7;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, #e9b1a7, #cf0a0a);
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #e9b1a7, #cf0a0a);
  padding: 0 1em;
  position: relative;
  right: 1em;
  margin-right: auto;
}
span.gradient:hover {
  animation-name: logo-hover;
  animation-duration: 0.3s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.17, 0.57, 0.31, 0.85);
}

h1.logo {
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 1.75em;
  line-height: 0.75em;
  color: #fff;
}

h1.logo a, a:active, a:hover, a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
}

.nav-link {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  border-top: 0.5px solid #ddd;
}

a:link, a:visited, a:active {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #e9b1a7;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.right {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}

.btn-nav {
  color: #e9b1a7;
  padding-left: 2em;
  padding-right: 2em;
}

@media (min-width: 800px) {
  #nav-wrapper {
    overflow: hidden;
  }

  #nav {
    overflow: hidden;
    flex-direction: row;
  }

  .nav-link {
    border-top: none;
  }

  .right {
    overflow: hidden;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    position: relative;
    left: 1.5em;
    height: auto;
  }

  .btn-nav {
    display: none;
  }

  .nav a:link.active, a:visited.active, a:active.active {
    background: #e9b1a7;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, #e9b1a7, #cf0a0a);
    background: linear-gradient(45deg, #e9b1a7, #cf0a0a);
    color: #fff;
  }

  .nav-link-span {
    transform: skew(20deg);
    display: inline-block;
  }

  .nav-link {
    transform: skew(-20deg);
    color: #777;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  .nav-link:last-child {
    padding-right: 3em;
  }

  a:hover.nav-link:not(.active) {
    color: #444;
    background: #ddd;
    background: linear-gradient(45deg, #fff, #ddd);
  }
}
@keyframes logo-hover {
  20% {
    padding-right: 0em;
  }
  100% {
    padding-right: 5em;
  }
}
</style>




<script>
var util = {
  mobileMenu() {
    $("#nav").toggleClass("nav-visible");
  },
  windowResize() {
    if ($(window).width() > 800) {
      $("#nav").removeClass("nav-visible");
    }
  },
  scrollEvent() {
    var scrollPosition = $(document).scrollTop();

    $.each(util.scrollMenuIds, function (i) {
      var link = util.scrollMenuIds[i],
        container = $(link).attr("href"),
        containerOffset = $(container).offset().top,
        containerHeight = $(container).outerHeight(),
        containerBottom = containerOffset + containerHeight;

      if (
        scrollPosition < containerBottom - 20 &&
        scrollPosition >= containerOffset - 20
      ) {
        $(link).addClass("active");
      } else {
        $(link).removeClass("active");
      }
    });
  }
};

$(document).ready(function () {
  util.scrollMenuIds = $("a.nav-link[href]");
  $("#menu").click(util.mobileMenu);
  $(window).resize(util.windowResize);
  $(document).scroll(util.scrollEvent);
});

</script>
```

Comment: Have you considered adjusting the width at which your navbar switches to vertical menu?

Comment: Seems more at the moment like a design issue, what are you trying to acheive?

Comment: @unknownpotato make the navbar shrink proportionally when the window is shrunk, instead of the text getting cut off.

Comment: @esszed I was thinking of eventually switching to a mobile detector thing, but its messed up even when on a laptop. It the window is less than 3/4 of my screen the navbar gets messed up.

Comment: Instead of `em` you could use `vh`, which is always 1% of the screen height. See [MDN docs: css units](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Values_and_units#lengths).

Comment: @peterkrebs that def helps, it goes from this (https://ibb.co/N9wS2Gchttps://ibb.co/W25b4Z1) to this (https://ibb.co/N9wS2Gc). Is there a way to make the whole thing shrink proportionally tho? Like dragging down the top right corner of the navbar.

Comment: I was experimenting with giving the font height `vh` as well. Depends what you want from the design. Maybe you need media queries for specific widths to make different screens sizes work. A general solution is harder to find.

Comment: @peterkrebs How could I maintain a padding on top of and underneath the text?

Comment: A simple solution would be to give the parent element some padding (also in `vh` if it looks good to you). This is usually better control than [line-height etc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font#constituent_properties).

Comment: @peterkrebs I'm not so knowledgeable, how do I know what the parent element is?

Comment: The parent element in your case is the `span class="u-nav"` around the text.

Answer (score 1):

Try implementing % in your stylesheet for fonts and divs!
For example, if you want a line of text or a container within a container to adjust in size when the parent container shrinks, you can have your interior elements set to something like

```
elementName{ max-width: 75%}
```

See if that helps with some of the elements inside the navWrapper.

Answer (score 0):

Set the navbar's height to 10vh or less/more. ##vh = ##% of display height. There is also 100vw. = ##% of display width.